# 404 not found error only in one route Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-7

I am refactoring my code and getting **404 Page not found** error in one route. I tried every possible solution but no luck. My route is give below:

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    .... other routes
    
    Route::prefix('product')->group(function () {
        .... other routes

        Route::prefix('category')->group(function () {
            Route::get('/', function () {
                dd('check');
            });

            <!-- Route::get('/', 'ProductCategoryController@index')->name('product_category_index'); -->
           
            .... other routes

        });
    });
});
```

In debugbar I am getting the exception:

**No query results for model [App\Product] category
F:\bvend\bvend.web\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php#389
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException**

I have no longer **App\Category model** in my code. Instead I have **App\ProductCategory**

I have no clue what the mistake is. Please help.

Comment: How are you trying to access this route?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/product/category/  @Remul

Comment: Do you have a route that looks something like this: `admin/product/{product}`? Looks like a route conflict to me, maybe try placing `Route::prefix('category')` directly after `Route::prefix('product')`

Comment: This is for Class mismatch,  run `composer dump-autoload` hope the problem will gone

Comment: Hey !! it worked like charm.. can you please tell me where was the conflict? it seems just changing the code order. thanks a lot @Remul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that two routes are conflicting with each other.

Lets say you have the following two routes with the following order:

```
admin/product/{product}

admin/product/category
```

When you try to access `admin/product/category` you are actually accessing `admin/product/{product}` with `category` as the value for the route parameter `{product}`.

That is why you get the error `No query results for model [App\Product] category`, it is trying to search for a product with the id `category`.

Now if you change the order:

```
admin/product/category

admin/product/{product}
```

Now the route `admin/product/category` has a higher priority than `admin/product/{product}`, so you actually can access your desired route, instead of getting matched into the `admin/product/{product}` route.

Comment: Great Explaination. !!

Comment: @Remul, What is the solution ?

Comment: @abu-abu Changing the order of the routes fixes the problem

Comment: @Remul I'm new to laravel, I've looked everywhere for a solution. Thanks for this